# VS2015, Angular4: bundle.js files from dist folder not getting copied to published folder

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, publish

I have a MVC5 + Angular4 Project. In the project Pre-Build event, I have mentioned

> ng build -prod

But When I publish the project, no files get copied to published dist folder.

Comment: it should be `ng build --prod`

Comment: @SebastianHildebrandt I tried with both -prod and --prod but with no success.